# about HBASE DISK IO

Tags: hadoop, hbase, disk

hbase In a high-density random read scenario, the current bottleneck appears in the disk throughput, but the disk IOPS is not high, if I reduce the blocksize of the table, can increase iops to reduce disk throughput?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How many IOPS you are doing, what are metrics of the machine you are using, how much data is there?

Comment: now running metrics:
table blocksize: 4k
disk iops:500
disk throughput:60MB